# Gauss Seidel using OpenMP | Linear Equations solving

Tags: c++, openmp, linear-algebra

**I am doing a code on Gauss Seidel using OpenMP to solve a system of linear equations.
But I am not getting the correct output.
The output comes correct if n is set to 1.
The algorithm seems right to me though.
Can anyone help?**

Code:

> 

```
    int seidel_p(double *A, double *b, double *x, int n)
{
    double *dx;
    dx = (double*) calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    int epsilon = 1.0e-4;
    int i,j,k,id;
    double dxi;
    double sum;
    for(int i =0; i<n ; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
    }

    int maxit = 2*n*n;

    for(k=0; k<maxit; k++)
   {
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
         dx[i] = b[i];
         #pragma omp parallel shared(A,x)
         {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(i!=j)
                {
                    dxi += A[i*n+j]*x[j];
                }
            }

            #pragma omp critical
               dx[i] -= dxi;
         }
         dx[i] /= A[i*n +i];
         x[i] = dx[i];
         sum += ( (dx[i] >= 0.0) ? dx[i] : -dx[i]);
         if(sum<= epsilon) break;

      }
   }

   for( int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++ )
   {
        printf("\t\t%f\n", dx[i]);
   }

    free(dx);
}
```

Comment: First of all you miss a "#pragma omp for". Right now every thread is running the whole loop (and should get the same result). Second you have a race condition on dxi, so you should add a reduction clause to that pragma. Then you wont need the critical section, as you can perform that subtraction outside the parallel region.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a VERY good reason to do this yourself, don't. There are lots of libraries that do this (and more). Eigen is a header only library, check it out.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

You could also use BLAS / LAPACK of which there are many implementations.

https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack (this implementation is not particularly optimized).

If you insist on rolling your own implementation the first thing you should check is if works with just a single thread. You can try this by setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` equal to 1 or by callin `omp_set_num_threads(1)`. If that works then you know your algorithm is correct it is just your use of OpenMP that is broken.

Comment: After checking correctness at 1 thread, assuming you're looking for performance, optimize it at 1 thread, continuing to check performance.  For example, you would wish to assure that the inner product is simd optimized.  As for OpenMP, you don't get the effect of compiler checking for private clause unless you set default(none).